# Playing videos in a paging adapter

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, exoplayer, android-paging-3

I have been trying to paginate data from firebase firestore using paging 3 library.
I have followed this article - https://medium.com/@ericampire/firestore-pagination-with-paging-3-762e371cc57f. 
My database holds url to videos and their thumbnails, along with some ids, title and other meta data. The pagination seems to be working fine. Is there a way to play videos in the recyclerview on scrolling using an exoplayer? Something that is used in some other applications like Youtube or Facebook? I have seen some examples like these- https://codingwithmitch.com/blog/playing-video-recyclerview-exoplayer-android/

 But the video urls are hardcoded and the data is not being paginated either. This will probably will require some custom implementations/additions to the paging adapter. So, is there any way, or any samples that demonstrate this use-case?

Comment: There's also another [approach](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df).

Comment: @AlexMamo , yeah I have seen that approach too. Not really related to playing videos in an exoplayer on scrolling I am afraid. Still, that article is also nice. Almost the same as the article I mentioned in my question.